# Trim string in Powershell using String.Replace

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to strip Active Directory's "DistinguishedName" attribute down to just the most specific OU title. For example, I am given:

```
CN=Smith\, Tom,OU=Developers,OU=Users,DC=myOrganization,DC=com
```

And I want this reduced to:

```
Developers
```

I have tried doing this without success (assume the variable is storing the DistinguisedName as above):

```
$disName = $disName.Replace("CN(*)OU=", "")
$disName = $disName.Replace(",OU(*)=com", "")
```

These statements are making no change to the string.

I am new to using regex in Powershell so I assume I'm just making a syntax mistake but the concept is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler to use a regular expression for this kind of data extraction, as others have already suggested, because `String.Replace` doesn't support things like non-greedy matches. I would recommend using a slightly more elaborate regular expression, though:

```
^.*?,\s*ou=(.*?),\s*(?:ou|dc).*$
```

because the suggestions you got so far will produce undesired results when the OU name contains characters like spaces or commas.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $dn = 'CN=Smith\, Tom,OU=Developers\, Foo,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com'
PS C:\> $dn -replace '^.*?,\s*ou=(.*?),\s*(?:ou|dc).*$', '$1'
Developers\, Foo
PS C:\> $dn -replace '^CN.*?OU=|,.*$'
Developers\
PS C:\> [regex]::Match($dn, 'OU=(\w+),').Groups[1].Value
Users
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
$attribute = "CN=Smith\, Tom,OU=Developers,OU=Users,DC=myOrganization,DC=com"    
[regex]::Match($attribute, 'OU=(\w+),').Groups[1].Value
```

Output:

> Developers

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what `(\w+)` and `Groups[1]` are doing?

Comment: Explaination copied from regex101.com: 
/OU=(\w+),/
OU= matches the characters OU= literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing group (\w+)
\w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
, matches the character , literally

Comment: Groups[1] selects the second group (containing the capturing group) from [regex]::Match()

Answer (score 0):

```
^CN.*?OU=|,.*$
```

You can use this and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rX1tE6/6